# relative permittivity in drude theory

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light

I have a probably stupid dilemma; studying the Drude theory of metals we found $\epsilon_r = 1-\frac{\omega_p^2}{\omega^2}$. Now if $\omega>\omega_p$ it follows that $\epsilon_r <1$ so the refractive index $n$ must be $< 1$ too. If that is true, the e.m. wave can propagate in the metal with speed greater than the speed of light. What am I missing?

Comment: Have a look at 31.3 http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_31.html